# Intersection of union of crazy intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am looking at two sets $X:=[0,1]$ and $V:= X \cap \mathbb{Q}= \{v_1,v_2,...\}$. For each $n,k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge1}$ I define an interval  $I_{n,k}:= X \cap (v_n-2^{-(n+k)},v_n+2^{-(n+k)}) $. Now I want to understand this crazy intersection: $$ D := \bigcap_{k\ge1} \bigcup_{n\ge1} I_{n,k} \ \ \ .$$

I think I could already prove that $V \subseteq D$ (please correct me if I'm wrong). Is this a strict inclusion or is there is equality between $V$ and $D$? My main problem is, that I cannot make proper intuitive sense of the set $D$. Thanks for any idea!

Comment: $V\neq D$. In fact, it follows from [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) that $D$ is uncountable (Hint: Reductio ad absurdum).

Comment: Certainly $V\subseteq D$. For any $k$, each $v_m\in I_{m,k}$, so $v_m$ is in the inner union; so $v_m$ is in the intersection of those unions, i.e. in $D$. $D$ is a countable intersection of open sets, hardly "crazy" :)

Comment: Countable intersection of open sets can be quite non-intuitive.

Comment: The inner union is decreasing in $k$ (in the sense of inclusion). Each of those unions is an open cover of the rationals by balls of decreasing radius. You can think of $D$ as some sort of limit as the overall size of the balls decreases to $0$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Sure, they can be complex. But that's a relative notion: they're at level 2 among Borel sets (classically, they're the [$G_{\delta}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) sets), a hierarchy that doesn't quit until stage $\omega_1$. And compared to some choice-based constructions (the Vitali set, a Hamel basis), they're eminently sane.

Comment: thanks for the great comments. how can i show that D is uncountable? I can apply baires theorem to show that $D$ is dense in $X$ but it could still be countable am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explicit construction of a number that is in $D$ but not in $V$:

Start by setting $a_0=0, b_0=1$, and repeat the following steps for each $k\ge 1$:

- Let $n$ be the smallest $n$ such that $a_{k-1}<v_n<b_{k-1}$ and $v_n\ne v_k$.
- Let $\varepsilon = \min(2^{-(k+n_k)}, |v_n-v_k|, v_n-a_{k-1}, b_{k-1}-v_n)$.
- Let $a_k = v_n-\varepsilon/2$ and $b_k = v_n+\varepsilon/2 $.

Then $[a_k,b_k]$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of closed intervals such that

- $[a_k, b_k]\subseteq \cup_n I_{n,k} $
- For every $k\ge 1$ we have $v_k \notin [a_k,b_k]$

The number $x=\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k$ is in every $[a_k,b_k]$, and so it must be in $D$ (due to the first of the above properties), but cannot be in $V$ (due to the second property).

It is easy to adapt this construction to produce $2^{\aleph_0}$ *different* $x\in D\setminus V$, such as by replacing $[a_k,b_k]$ with its left or right third after each round.

Answer (score 2):

(1)Look up a proof of the Baire Category Theorem for completely metrizable spaces. It's quite simple.(2) A corollary is that if $F=\{f_n :n\in N\}$ is a non-empty countable family of dense open subsets of $[0,1]$, then $\cap F$ is uncountable, because if $S=\{r_n : n\in N\}$ is any countable set then $G=\{f_n\backslash \{r_n\} \}$ is also a non-empty countable family of dense open sets so $\cap G$ is dense in $[0,1]$. So $\phi\ne \cap G=(\cap F)\backslash S$  so $\cap F\ne S.$ In your Q, the set $D$ is uncountable so $D\ne [0,1]\cap Q$.

Comment: i will check the proof for complete metric spaces. thank you!

Comment: I said "for complete metric spaces" because I have seen a generalization (in  Engelking, General Topology) also called the Baire category theorem. If others name your  theorem after you, a generalized version might still carry your name.